# Histogram for discrete values with matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I sometimes have to histogram discrete values with matplotlib.  In that case, the choice of the binning can be crucial: if you histogram [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] using 10 bins, one of the bins will have twice as many counts as the others.  In other terms, the binsize should normally be a multiple of the discretization size.

While this simple case is relatively easy to handle by myself, does anyone have a pointer to a library/function that would take care of this automcatically, including in the case of floating-point data where the discretization size could be slightly varying due to FP rounding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Given the title of your question, I will assume that the discretization size is constant.

You can find this discretization size (or at least, strictly, ***n*** times that size as you may not have two adjacent samples in your data)

```
np.diff(np.unique(data)).min()
```

This finds the unique values in your data (`np.unique`), finds the differences between then (`np.diff`).  The unique is needed so that you get no zero values.  You then find the minimum difference.  There could be problems with this where discretization constant is very small - I'll come back to that.

Next - you want your values to be in the middle of the bin - your current issue is because both 9 and 10 are on the edges of the last bin that matplotlib automatically supplies, so you get two samples in one bin.

So - try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = range(11)
data = np.array(data)

d = np.diff(np.unique(data)).min()
left_of_first_bin = data.min() - float(d)/2
right_of_last_bin = data.max() + float(d)/2
plt.hist(data, np.arange(left_of_first_bin, right_of_last_bin + d, d))
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image: Histogram of sample data]

---

#### Small non-integer discretization

We can make a bit more of a testing data set e.g.

```
import random 

data = []
for _ in range(1000):
    data.append(random.randint(1,100))
data = np.array(data)
nasty_d = 1.0 / 597 #Arbitrary smallish discretization
data = data * nasty_d
```

If you then run that through the array above and have a look at the `d` that the code spits out you will see

> ```
> >>> print(nasty_d)
> 0.0016750418760469012
> >>> print(d)
> 0.00167504187605
> ```

So - the detected value of `d` is not the "real" value of `nasty_d` that the data was created with.  However - with the trick of shifting the bins by half of `d` to get the values in the middle - it shouldn't matter ***unless*** your discretization is very very small so your down in the limits of precision of a float ***or*** you have 1000s of bins and the difference between detected `d` and "real" discretization can build up to such a point that one of the bins "misses" the data point.  It's something to be aware of, but probably won't hit you.

An example plot for the above is

[image: Example histogram with small discretization]

---

#### Non uniform discretization / most appropriate bins...

For further more complex cases, you might like to look at [this blog post I found](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/09/12/dynamic-programming-in-python).  This looks at ways of automatically "learning" the best bin widths from (continuous / quasi-continuous) data, referencing multiple standard techniques such as [Sturges' rule and Freedman and Diaconis' rule](http://www.vosesoftware.com/ModelRiskHelp/index.htm#Presenting_results/Histogram_plots/Determining_the_width_of_histogram_bars.htm) before developing its own Bayesian dynamic programming method.

If this is your use case - the question is far broader and may not be suited to a definitive answer on Stack Overflow, although hopefully the links will help.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize that shifting by half a bin would solve most issues I was worrying about (and indeed, I was talking about uniform discretization, not about Freedman-Diaconis type rules, which I am aware of).  I think you have a typo in the code when you say "So - the detected value of d is not the "real" value of d", though.

Comment: Thanks. Good spot on the typo - I've cleaned it up now.

Comment: Note to self: useful histogram options: ``plt.hist(x, bins = bins, density = True, color = "green", ec = "black"`` where ``ec`` stands for "edge color".

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps a less-complete answer than [J Richard Snape's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838992/j-richard-snape), but one that I recently learned and that I found intuitive and easy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# great seed
np.random.seed(1337)

# how many times will a fair die land on the same number out of 100 trials.
data = np.random.binomial(n=100, p=1/6, size=1000)

# the trick is to set up the bins centered on the integers, i.e.
# -0.5, 0.5, 1,5, 2.5, ... up to max(data) + 1.5. Then you substract -0.5 to
# eliminate the extra bin at the end.
bins = np.arange(0, data.max() + 1.5) - 0.5

# then you plot away
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_ = ax.hist(data, bins)
ax.set_xticks(bins + 0.5)
```

[image]

Turns out that around 16/100 throws will be the same number!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! This should be a built-in feature of histogram

Answer (score 18):

Not exactly what OP asked for, but calculating bins is not necessary if all values are integers.

[`np.unique(d, return_counts=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns a tuple of a list of unique values as a first element and their counts as a second element. This can be plugged directly into [`plt.bar(x, height)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) using the star operator:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = [1,1,2,4,4,4,5,6]
plt.bar(*np.unique(d, return_counts=True))
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

Note that this technically works with floating point numbers as well, however the results might be unexpected because a bar is created for every number.

Comment: simple and elegant, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

another version for just handling the simple case in a small amount of code!  this time using [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`matplotlib.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# same seed/data as Manuel Martinez to make plot easy to compare
np.random.seed(1337)
data = np.random.binomial(100, 1/6, 1000)

values, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)

plt.vlines(values, 0, counts, color='C0', lw=4)

# optionally set y-axis up nicely
plt.ylim(0, max(counts) * 1.06)
```

giving me:

[image: matplotlib output]

which looks eminently readable